# package name doesn't match service name

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook, recipe

I am trying to write cookbook which will work under ubuntu and debian.
I am using package that has the same name in ubuntu and debian. But in debian package name doesn't match service name.

Example:

`ubuntu - package name = foo, service = foo.
debian - package name = foo, servie = xxxx`

I need the name to start/restart service explicitly or notify the service. So, what is the best way, to use right service name? Of course, I can predefine the name in attribute file for ubuntu and debian separatly, but I want to try to do this automatically.

Comment: Probably somebody familiar with this situation. I am talking about iptables-persistent package. It has been changed in latest debian. You can install iptables-persistent but service is netfilter-persistent. The problem is that, current cookbook is working with ubuntu trusty and I need backward compatibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As such differences occur in many cases, there is even an example for this is included in chef's documentation about the [service resource](https://docs.chef.io/resource_service.html):

```rb
service 'crond' do
  case node['platform']
  when 'redhat', 'centos', 'scientific', 'fedora', 'amazon'
    service_name 'crond'
  when 'debian', 'ubuntu', 'suse'
    service_name 'cron'
  end
  action [:start, :enable]
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the replay.  I want to try to find a solution, which allows to avoid editing cookbook, every time when service name is changed.

Comment: You can include conditions for different platform versions, too. Try to not overcomplicate things - anything can change with new OS versions